# Why can't I find Internet Explorer in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-search

I press the start button, and start typing "Internet Explorer".  Nothing matches.

If I type iexplore.exe, then it matches on the file.

How can I get IE by typeing "Internet Explorer"?

Comment: In C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ is there a shortcut to Internet Explorer? (Just wondering, since on my computer it works and searching "Internet Explorer" just finds this particular shortcut which links to iexplore.exe)

Comment: Do you have 'Internet Explorer' listed anywhere under 'Start > All Programs'?

Comment: @Nano8Blazex - no, the shortcut was not there.  I created it and the problem has been fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your computer has not fully indexed the hard drive yet or something. Because typing "Internet Explorer" Brings it up on my windows 7 install.

If you still cannot find it after you let your computer index, you could pin it to your start menu or your task bar, so you don't have to type to find it.

If you need Internet Explorer for a few sites, I can understand. But if you are using it as your full time browser, **I would recommend looking at some of the other browsers.** They are generally more secure, faster, have more features, and they support more recent web technologies such as HTML-5 and the  tag.

http://www.mozilla.com/ Firefox

http://www.opera.com/ Opera

http://www.google.com/chrome Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Isn't "ie" enough?  If it isn't, it oughta be.